# Read Text file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I want to read text file that is placed on server. for example my file is placed on this link: http://mysite.com/files/objects.txt
How can I read the contents of this file into `NSString`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSError* e;
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:@"http://mysite.com/files/objects.txt" encoding:NSASCIIEncoding error:&e]
if(e != nil) {
  //There was an error
}
//Everything good
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the syntax has changed with recent iOS updates...

```
NSError* err;
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<your URL goes here>"];
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url
                                             encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                error:&err];
```